# Get selected folder from sidebar in Sublimetext

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm looking for method to get the path from folder that exist in the sidebar.
So far, I found this way:

```py
class AddConfigCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, files):
        if not files:
            files.append(sublime.active_window().active_view().file_name())
```

which return me the path **only if it a file**, but if it a folder it return me None.
The files parameter came from `Side Bar.sublime-menu` file:

```js
{
    "caption": "Create New Config",
    "command": "add_config",
    "args": {
      "files": []
    }
}
```

Another option that maybe can help in some way is to get the "where" line from the function 'Find in folder' which return the path of file/folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "args" variable defines all the input sublime will send to your method. "files" is an array that contains all the chosen files on the sidebar, and files **ONLY**.

To get the directories chosen you need to pass the "paths" variable on your sublime-menu file like so:

```
{
"caption": "Create New Config",
"command": "add_config",
"args": {
  "paths": []
}
```